# pyqt: Variable values in QMessageBox output?

Tags: python, string, qmessagebox

Right now I'm displaying a window with text in a QMessageBox. It works and displays the text accurately.

```
 profBox = QMessageBox()
 QMessageBox.about(self,'Profile', "Gender: <br /> Age: < br />") #Ideal output is gender: F (stored in a variable) and Age: X (also stored in a variable)
```

I would like to include the value of certain variables to put after Gender & Age but I am curious about the syntax for including variable values. Do I convert them to strings first? How do I include them since an .about box can only take a maximum of three arguments?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use `QMessageBox.about(self, ...)` instead of `self.about(...)` or `profBox.about(...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> gender = 'M'
>>> age = 33

>>> "Gender: {}<br /> Age: {}< br />".format(gender, age)
'Gender: M<br /> Age: 33< br />'
```

or use [`%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> "Gender: %s<br /> Age: %s< br />" % (gender, age)
'Gender: M<br /> Age: 33< br />'
```