# How to display variable in qmessagebox using creator in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I am trying to display a variable with some message in qmessagebox using creator. I found similar post here: [pyqt: Variable values in QMessageBox output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139023/pyqt-variable-values-in-qmessagebox-output) but it does not work within the creator. Any suggestions how to amend the code below so that it worked?:

```
purchaseValue = col2SumUp.sum()
msgbox = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "Value: %s" % purchaseValue, QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the title parameter, the following is working for me:

```
purchaseValue = 125.2
msgbox = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "Title", "Value: %s" % purchaseValue, QMessageBox.Ok)
msgbox.exec_()
```

[image: QMessageBox]